# C#: MethodInfo.Invoke a method that needs input from user to process

Tags: c#, invoke, blocking, methodinfo

I have a DLL file that has a method inside it which creates a FolderBrowserDialog and waits for user selection to proceed. Here is its code:

```
        public void setRoot() {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            root = fbd.SelectedPath;
            searchRoot();
        }
    }
```

However, on another program I am trying to invoke this method and I get the program waiting forever. My guess is that the invoking program is waiting for the FileBrowserDialog to select a file. This is the output:
[MethodInfo.Invoke(class object, parameters)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p7r7.png)
How can I get past that and make the invoking program select the directory for that invoked method?

Comment: Start by showing us some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method called with `MethodInfo.Invoke` is not different than one called directly from code. It's the same code that's being run, will still run on the same thread, with the same permissions as a direct call. If your Reflection-invoked method hangs while working fine without reflection, there's something *else* that's causing it.

It looks, from your screenshot, that you're running it in a Console application. I'm guessing the other app, isn't a console app, which means it has a running message pump waiting for Windows messages, making the dialog work. Running Windows dialogs in a console application won't work so easily.

Comment: I added [STAThread] before my Main and yes it did pop out the GUI.
However, I am designing an application that tests multiple DLLs. How can I make it test multiple files without hanging by any method that requires user input?